# JQuery - $(document).getElementById('id').submit(function{}); unedifined not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, undefined, typeerror

I've been searching or a solution to my problem, but none of the aswers I find are useful.

I try to make an automatic form that submits itself when the page loads.

```
$(document).getElementById('ticketCount').submit(function(){
    $.ajax({
        method:$(this).attr('method'),
        url:$(this).attr('action'),
        data:$(this).serialize()
    })
    .done(function(data){
        $('#ticketCount').html(data);
    })
    .error(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
  });
```

My console tells me that: "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function".
I don't think I made a mistake (I know this is case-sensitive), and I already used $(document).ready(), $(document).keyup(function{}) somewhere else in the same .js file, so I don't think the problem comes from $(document)..

I can't ind where my mistake is...

Thanks for your answers!

Comment: `$(document).` returns a jQuery object which does not have a method called `getElementById`

Comment: Where did you see this kind of code??? However you could use `$(document.getElementById('ticketCount'))` but why would you use it?!

Comment: You have lots of error , including `method` is not a property of ajax , instead use `type`

Comment: Thanks or this. The error is gone.

@A. Wolff : As I said, I want to do a form that submits itself when a page loads (Asking for information to show)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.getElementById() -> this is javascript syntax to get the DOM element having a particular unique Id.

in jQuery it is deferent. You nead to have a selector for that DOM element

Many selectors are there. Here you nead ID SELECTOR.
that is: **#id**

so you need to write like:

```
$('#ticketCount').submit(function(){
.............................
```

If you want to submit automatically when the page load use:

```
window.onload = function(){
  $('#ticketCount').trigger("submit");
};
```

Comment: Got it. Now, how would I make this submit automatic when the page loads?

Comment: Be carefull with `window.onload`, as it might overwrite any existing `window.onload`. Instead I'd recommend using `$(document).ready`.

Comment: @Kim Hogeling : My whole script is inside a $(document).ready, is that a problem?

Comment: @Sideness : No, that is not a problem. It is absolutely correct that way!

Answer (score 2):

You've got 3 mistakes.

**First**: `$(document)` is not a DOM element, so `.getElementById` is undefined. Instead use the jQuery selector.

**Second**: `.submit` requires a user to press the submit button. Instead let's use `$(document).ready`

Change

```
 $(document).getElementById('ticketCount').submit(function(){
```

into

```
$(document).ready(function(){
```

**Third**: The jQuery ajax function doesn't have a property called `method`. Instead it has the `type` instead

Change

```
method:$(this).attr('method'),
```

into

```
type:$(this).attr('method'),
```

Comment: Can please tell OP Why didn't work, it will help to OP as well as future readers.

Comment: Or, for completism: `document.getElementById('ticketCount').submit()` or `document.querySelector('#ticketCount').submit()`, using [`HTMLFormElement.submit()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLFormElement.submit); jQuery is almost entirely not needed here.

Comment: I want to form to automaticly submit when the page loads. The code you gave me waits for the user to click on "submit"

Comment: Updated my answer with an explanation ;-)

Answer (score 1):

use `setTimeout`

```
setTimeout(function(){
var elem = document.getElementById('ticketCount');
var $elem = $(elem);
 $.ajax({
        type:$elem.attr('method'),
        url:$elem.attr('action'),
        data:$elem.serialize()
    })
    .done(function(data){
        $elem.html(data);
    })
    .error(function(data){
        console.log(data);
    });
},500);
```

Comment: You made a number of changes from OP's original question. While I may or may not agree with your answer, you should offer more description to what you have done and why. Thanks!

Comment: thanks! This works! (Exept that I changed document.getElementById('ticketCount'); by $('#ticketCount'). But this was what I was looking for! Thanks!

Comment: Your solution worked, but I find the one I accepted "cleaner"...
Thanks anyway! Have a good day!

Comment: what if the page takes more than 500ms to load?

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ticketCount").submit(function(){
```

change the code

```
$(document).getElementById('ticketCount').submit(function(){
```

to

```
 $("#ticketCount").submit(function(){
```

Comment: Did you really take four minutes to post exactly the same answer as already posted?

Comment: I didnt seen the post when i post sorry for that