# getElementById does not set text correctly

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a template which im trying to change the content of a span using getElementById.innerHTML in my ajax success function however, it is not working. I do not see what the issue is since when I print out my data it is correct. Currently I have template like this:

```
<div class="post-ctr">
    <div>
      <span id="like-count-d"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="like-section">
     <!-- likeBtn Form is here which gets updated -->
    </div>
</div>
```

my jQuery code is:

```
$(document).ready(function (e) {
    $('.post-ctr').on("click", ".likeBtn", function (e) {
        var btn = $(this)
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        var tk = $(this).attr("data-token");
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: $(this).attr("data-url"),
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { 'csrfmiddlewaretoken':tk },
            success: function (data){
                $(btn).closest(".like-section").html(data.post_likes);
                $(document).getElementById('like-count-d').innerHTML = data.likescount;
            },
            error: function(rs, e){
                console.log(rs.responeText);
            },
        });
    });
})
```

How can I manage to update the `span` element with that id?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Update div with jQuery ajax response html](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064666/update-div-with-jquery-ajax-response-html)

Comment: Why not directly call  `$('#like-count-d').html(data.likescount)` ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JQuery - $(document).getElementById('id').submit(function{}); unedifined not a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23341103/jquery-document-getelementbyidid-submitfunction-unedifined-not-a-f)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the jQuery library selector `$` is being mistaken for native JavaScript functions.

In jQuery, when you select the `document` with `$`, you’re not really dealing with the document itself, you’re dealing with some “wrapper” object for the document, which gets generated by jQuery's `$`, and in that wrapper object, there’s no concept of `innerHTML`, or `getElementById`, but there is `$(document.body).html("something")`.

If you wanted to select and edit the HTML of a particular element with an ID, then use the `#` operator in a string, and call the `.html` method on it, like this:

```
$("#like-count-d").html(data.likescount/*or other string*/);
```

If you want to use `getElementById` and `innerHTML`, then don’t use jQuery’s `$`, just use a reference to the node itself, like this:

```
document.getElementById('like-count-d').innerHTML = data.likescount;
```

and visa versa, if you don't want to use jQuery, then use `document.getElementById`.

Alternatively, if you want to use the jQuery-style selectors but don't want to use jQuery itself, you can always use the jQuery selector strings inside of the `document.querySelector` or `document.querySelectorAll` functions, and set the innerHTML to that, like:

```
document. querySelector("#like-count-d").innerHTML = data.likescount;
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use html() or text() of jQuery for the same. Kindly refer to this.

```
$("#like-count-d").html(data.likescount);
$("#like-count-d").text(data.likescount);
```